# Does sequelize cache common requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

So my question is very simple. If I will perform the same query a lot of time per second/minutes (like User.find(test_user_id)) it will send request to database each time or it's just cache query result somehow?

Comment: Sequelize doesn't do any DB caching, but I love this module for Redis cache https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-redis-cache

Answer (score 4):

In your example, User.find(test_user_id), User is the database table model you are querying and .find is your data retrieval method. From the [sequelize site](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/models#block-25-line-1) the finder method is defined as follows:

"Finder methods are designed to get data from the database."

If you call User.find(...) you will be querying your database for each query request.